# How break works in infinite loop?

Tags: go, goroutine

In the below code:

```
data.WaitForGoroutine.Add(1)
go func() {
    for {
        select {
        case msg := <-someCh:
            data.DataCh <- fmt.Sprintf("Received messages: key %s, value: %s\n", string(msg.Key), string(msg.Value))
        case <-data.Signal:
            close(data.DataCh)
            break
        }
    }
    data.WaitForGoroutine.Done()
}()
```

---

Linter complains that `data.WaitForGoroutine.Done()` is unreachable code.

Doesn't `break` break from `for{}`?

Comment: Technically, it breaks out of the `select`. If you don't include this break, you can end up triggering multiple cases.

Comment: @David Go does not have fall-through on `switch` and `select` cases.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco, https://golang.org/ref/spec#Fallthrough_statements

Comment: @JimB Interesting.  I know I've seen that keyword before, but forgot about it until now. I should correct: Go does not have fall-through as a default behaviour in `switch` and `select` statements, therefore you don't need `break` to prevent it.

Answer (score 4):

Per the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Break_statements):

> A "break" statement terminates execution of the innermost "for",
> "switch", or "select" statement within the same function.

Your `break` terminates the `select`, not the `for`. If you want to break out of the for, use labels (same section of the spec). eg:

```golang
OuterLoop:
    for {
        select {
        case msg := <-someCh:
            data.DataCh <- fmt.Sprintf("Received messages: key %s, value: %s\n", string(msg.Key), string(msg.Value))
        case <-data.Signal:
            close(data.DataCh)
            break OuterLoop
        }
    }
```